# mounting smb at boot with /etc/fstab

Tags: boot, fstab

related to thread [How to edit /etc/fstab properly for network drive?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178187/how-to-edit-etc-fstab-properly-for-network-drive/178188#178188)

i have added the following line to `/etc/fstab`

```
//192.168.0.52/public /mnt/PC52/public cifs username=guest,password="" 0 0
```

if i call `sudo mount -a` the directory mounts and all works fine, but if i reboot the computer it fails to add at boot, i feel like its something to do with the blank password that i have passed, if i omit the password field completely it prompts for a password during boot and if i just press enter it boots and works

Comment: Try passing a credentials file instead

Comment: Does this mount *really* need to be active during boot? If not, you should consider using autofs and mount it when it's accessed.

Comment: thanks, this link was useful, <https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorted it.

as its an open directory it doesn't matter what password i send, as long as i add the password field setting the password to something it works.

changing the line in `fstab` to the following, it works fine

//192.168.0.52/public /mnt/PC52/public cifs username=guest,password=123 0 0

Comment: Since `/etc/fstab` has `644` permissions, I would recommend using a keyring to store the credentials, or save the file as root to `/root/.cifs` and `chmod 600` it.

Comment: if it was an actual password i would agree but as it is a guest account i did not think it mattered

Comment: Makes sense, I thought you were just using guest as a placeholder

Comment: That's a great way to prevent your system from booting when your smb machine is down.

Comment: Mayhew, do you care to elaborate on your apparat better approach or are you just trying to throw in downers on people trying to achieve anything, in all honesty i just want to be able to access the share point whenever it is available to be accessed.

Comment: Mayhew, i have shut the server down and booted up my computer, the computer boots up just fine as expected, the mount point failed to mount since it is not there, i don't see what the problem is.